# Test class for Static wrapper class methods

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I have a static method for which I am trying to write a test class for.

```
public with sharing class CDX_OrderSearchScreenController{

public class StandingOrdersWrapper{

//Variable declarations

public StandingOrdersWrapper(CDX_Staging_Order__c stagingRecord)
{
  //Code
}
}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
//Need to Write a Test class for this method
    public static List<StandingOrdersWrapper> getStandingOrders(Id stagingId, String stagingRecordData) {
//code
}
}
```

The Test class I have is follows

```
@isTest
public  class CDX_OrderSearchScreenController_Test {
@isTest
    public static void getStandingOrdersTest_1()
    {
       List<CDX_OrderSearchScreenController.StandingOrdersWrapper> standingOrders; 

       CDX_Staging_Order__c testRecord = new CDX_Staging_Order__c(Name = 'Test Data', CDX_Date_of_Message__c = Date.newInstance(2020, 01, 10));
insert testRecord; 

       standingOrders = CDX_OrderSearchScreenController.getStandingOrders(testRecord.Id, JSON.serialize(testRecord)); 
    }
}
}
```

The above code is not covering the method at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the code related to `getStandingOrders`. If you are not using the constructor then the line won't be covered.

You can either provide more details about your code or change the getStandingOrders method (just as a test) to something like:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
//Need to Write a Test class for this method
public static List < StandingOrdersWrapper > getStandingOrders(Id stagingId, String stagingRecordData) {
    //code
    CDX_Staging_Order__c testStagingOrder = [SELECT Id FROM CDX_Staging_Order__c LIMIT 1]; //Assuming you have CDX_Staging_Order__c records on your ORG;
    return new List<StandingOrdersWrapper>{new StandingOrdersWrapper(testStagingOrder)};
}
```

And then run the tests again to confirm the constructor is also covered.

Best regards!